# instant apps DAL failed

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am developing an instant app following the instructions given in  [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/index.html).

For app link I am using the tool "App links Assistant" under Tools. Under "App links assistant" > "Associate Website" I clicked on "Open Digital Asset Links File Generator" button and successfully generated the file. But failed to link and verify.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEK7A.png)

Does anybody have any idea how to resolve this? Also my instant app is not opening via its link.

**Note: My domain is SSL certified.**

Comment: First, verify if your app links are correct with https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator. Then you can use command line at “Testing a web URI intent” https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#testing
to check if your JSON file is valid as well as the manifest file.

Comment: I got the issue of "link and verify" resolved by updating android studio from canary 4 to 5. May be that was a bug in that old version. But still unable to open my instant app via link.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you’re trying to run your instant app, logs? Or does your link open the browser instead?

Comment: I didn't got any errors

Answer (score 0):

Your server does not have a valid SSL certificate. Make sure your `assetlinks.json` file can be accessed by HTTPS. You can simply check access by using curl:

```
curl https://yourdomain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

Comment: My domain is now SSL ceritified. But still cant open my instant app url in mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue of "link and verify" resolved by updating android studio from canary 4 to 5. May be that was a bug in that old version. But still unable to open my instant app via link.